# Plotting the (non-unique) solutions of ODE $\dot \gamma(t) = \sqrt{|\gamma(t)|}$ with Matlab

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab

Consider the ODE $$\dot \gamma(t) = \sqrt{|\gamma(t)|}$$ with initial data $\gamma(0) =x_0 = -c^2$.

Having fixed one value of $c$, the solutions of this Cauchy problem are not unique because one has $x(t) = -(t/2 - c)^2$ for $0 \le t \le 2c$, then the solution can stay at the origin for some time $2T(c)$ (also maybe infinite or zero) and then continue as $x(t) = (t/2 - T (c) - c)^2$ for $t \ge 2c + 2T(c)$.

- How can I draw these multiple characteristic lines of this problem by using Matlab? And how can I highlight (maybe in a different color) some of them? For example the one with $T(c) = 0$ and the one with $T(c) = \infty$?
- Usually, what numerical methods are used to solve (more complicated) ODEs where non-uniqueness of solutions occurs?

Comment: Matlab might not be the best option for your purpose. Perhaps try Mathematica if you or your school have license (use VectorPlot or StreamPlot for example), or Maxima if not (use plotdf)?

Comment: Why not try [sage](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/plotting/sage/plot/streamline_plot.html)?

Comment: @ablmf Would you mind adding an answer elaborating on that remark?